# How to choose the number of hidden layers in a seq2seq RNN according to expected length of i/o sequences?

Tags: neural-network, tensorflow, keras, recurrent-neural-network, lstm

I am trying to predict characteristics of a group of persons.
[image]
Each group contains a **unique** number of persons `N`.
Length of input feature vector per person `I` is constant (100).
Length of ​output prediction vector per person `O`​ is constant (200).

1. What would be the right choice of network architecture?
2. How many LSTM layers (and neuron blocks in a layer) would I need in case when

   - N = ~100? (sequences: ~10 000 → ~20 000)
   - N = ~400? (sequences: ~40 000 → ~80 000)
   - N = ~800? (sequences: ~80 000 → ~160 000)

Any advice on network architecture is appreciated.

Comment: I'm also interested in an answer to this. Did you figure it out?

Comment: I ended up using another network architecture.

Comment: Which one did you use? Could you post an explanation as an answer to your own question?